# How can I set an expression for an external image when the file name is coming from a stored procedure column

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder

My team and I are in the process of migrating from Crystal Reports to SQL Server Reporting Services. A handful of our reports involve what my team refer to as "dynamic external images". What this means is that in the report we would have this default blank image object, and then in the Graphic Location setting we would have the following function:

```
Trim({rpt_StoredProc;1.SignaturePath}) + Trim({rpt_StoredProc;1.SignatureId}) + ".jpg"
```

This way, we could pass through the directory path and the file name (minus the file extension) via the stored procedure.

I'm now trying to replicate this in SQL Server Reporting Services Report Builder and I'm running into a brick wall.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is your stored procedure added as a dataset in SSRS? If so, you should be able to reference them in much the same way, i.e. `=Trim(Fields!SignaturePath.Value) & Trim(Fields!SignatureId.Value) & ".jpg"`

Comment: Can you define in detail, `I'm running into a brick wall`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer!

```
="file://" & First(Fields!SignaturePath.Value, "rpt_StoredProc") & "\" & First(Fields!SignatureId.Value, "rpt_StoredProc") & ".JPG"
```

I thought I had already tried this and that it didn't work, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Your data relating to dynamic external images having been imported in SSRS should be accessible in a table using the data type varbinary(max). This can be accessed and utilised in an SSRS report either as a single field (ie in a header/title) or in matrix a field.

Both usages require you use the toolbox, (view and select toolbox) and left mouse click , drag "image" to your report, image source "database", use the field (select varbinary(max) field) , MIME type try "image/bmp" first, select the size to suit your needs.

and you should be good to go.

Best of luck.